# What is the Coffee SE position on posts generated by ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion

Across the Internet OpenAI’s ChatGPT has gained a lot of attention both within and outside the tech community.

There have been negative impacts on some SE sites, especially Stack Overflow.

How are we dealing with posts that are ChatGPT-generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until further notice we will be [adopting the SO policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/7035983) on ChatGPT posts, which means they are banned for almost all contributions, including questions, answers and comments.

This is in accordance with the [feedback from Community Management](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/310311) that leaves the decision on the topic to the individual sites as needed. For details on the Stack Exchange position and the reasoning behind the ban on SO, see [the SO Help Center article](https://For%20details%20on%20the%20official%20staff%20position,%20see%20the%20SO%20Help%20Center%20article%20on%20the%20topic.) on the topic.

Please note that due to the newness of ChatGPT, all decisions about ChatGPT can and probably will be changed and adjusted over time. The moderator team will be carefully monitoring both the impact of these posts on this site and the discussions and potentially ensuing policies across the network. Any updates will be communicated and discussed as needed.