# Please give us the no-AI banner

Tags: support, feature-request, status-review

Per [the announcement on network-wide meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396626/proposed-changes-to-help-center-articles-to-include-mention-of-ai-generated-cont), we need to specifically request the right banner UI, stating that AI-generated content is disallowed [based on the site’s decision](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/what-is-the-coffee-se-position-on-posts-generated-by-chatgpt).